Why does my render look like this, with artifacts?
On the viewport it looks ok, but when i render it, it has all this render artifacts... Does anybody have any clue why this is?
Thanks!


"Artifacts"? You mean the noise? Probably not enough samples and no denoising enabled...

Use the same engine as in the viewport. We don't see what kind of engine you're using to achieve the viewport result.

@ChristophWerner I thought the same thing, but it's Cycles in the viewport because there is the "Rendering Done" text in the top left corner of the screen. However, different settings are probably used for rendering and lighting, which we unfortunately cannot see.

Gaston, please upload your scene here. Replace your model by a dummy object if you like, but keep all your settings. In this way we may help.
